# Bug in Anaconda 5.2 for macOS Installer for Python 3.6? PySide and qt bindings not found after installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, anaconda, pyside

When trying to install Python 3.6 using the Anaconda 5.2 for macOS Installer I get the following errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/**init**.py", line 166, in 
>       from PySide import **version** as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 159, in main
>       from spyder.app import mainwindow
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 49, in 
>       requirements.check_qt()
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 39, in check_qt
>       import qtpy
>     File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/qtpy/**init**.py", line 172, in 
>       raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
>   qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found

I've seen these errors for different situations, the most relevant being explained in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6).

However, I wanted to post my question because the error occurs for the install using the latest version of anaconda for Mac, and I couldn't find a question related to that.