# Attribute error on python WebUI installation

Tags: python

I am trying to install WebUI using pip install WebUI and I got this error

```
Collecting WebUI
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/06/5f4ddb9a5d4acf9600be3a794bee670f778e43bbcd648e3f58cc8326cd6a/WebUI-0.1.7.zip
Collecting Flask==0.10.1 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/9c/149ba60c47d107f85fe52564133348458f093dd5e6b57a5b60ab9ac517bb/Flask-0.10.1.tar.gz
Collecting Jinja2==2.7.1 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/83/679b5592feb54e948d6599edf5dac61d2991778c3ecbef6b8041663f4740/Jinja2-2.7.1.tar.gz
Collecting MarkupSafe==0.18 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/cf/197c3b0f73224b84eb419a967f87565bcc0b0c1147012397e6bd2d45e253/MarkupSafe-0.18.tar.gz
Collecting Werkzeug==0.9.4 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d8/5e/8abc95630f9c4248edffed30592468f884e845ba656a959a12e452fafcec/Werkzeug-0.9.4.tar.gz
Collecting itsdangerous==0.23 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c1/6c/ceefb52b2a5d7d1f2b1b407a96892182161904478b9ef86049e7b8162cb6/itsdangerous-0.23.tar.gz
Collecting pyside==1.2.1 (from WebUI)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/32/63872fdc1d9e0de5aa0b05b9d1a17d868851c619cdc6998dd9d853556f1b/PySide-1.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\RBCABR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-546zsn2s\pyside\setup.py", line 82, in <module>
        from utils import rmtree
      File "C:\Users\RBCABR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-546zsn2s\pyside\utils.py", line 10, in <module>
        import popenasync
      File "C:\Users\RBCABR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-546zsn2s\pyside\popenasync.py", line 26, in <module>
        if subprocess.mswindows:
    AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'mswindows'
```

can someone explain the reason for this error and how to fix this?

Comment: What is your python version? If it is 3.5, then renaming mswindows to_mswindows should do the trick

Comment: 3.6.0 anyway where should I edit that?

Comment: you might have to download pyside and then change the line 26 inside popenasync.py, and from the folder run python setup.py install.

Comment: Also, you may want to check out this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6