# Need to install Pyside for matplotlib. Pyside Installation Error

Tags: python, installation

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\s38467\appdata\local\enthought\canopy\edm\envs\user\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\s38467\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3677kav\Pyside\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\s38467\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3677kav\Pyside\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\s38467\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3677kav\Pyside\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\s38467\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-b3677kav\Pyside\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
I'm currently running Python 3.5 using canopy env.

Answer (score 0):

You need PySide2

https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/

The original PySide doesn't support Python > 3.4

See also [Installing PySide for Python-3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6)

Comment: Do I need to do anything else? I pip install Pyside2, and it is telling me that Matplotlib requires external backends.