# Unable to install PySide for python3

Tags: python, pyside

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/python_code/CANalyzat0r-master $ pip install PySide
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting PySide
  Using cached PySide-1.2.4.tar.gz (9.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zvgnnffi/PySide/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-zvgnnffi/PySide/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-zvgnnffi/PySide/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-zvgnnffi/PySide/
    Complete output (1 lines):
    only these python versions are supported: [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: what is your python3 version?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6), Seems that issue is with your python version, Pyside will not be updated for version of python 3.5+. Instead, install [Pyside2](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python)

Comment: we did try installing Pyside2, but it said it is in already newest version