# How to force install package with Pip?

Tags: python

I am trying to install pyside with Python 3.8. It is stating that I need Python [(2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)]. Is there a way I can force install and override this requirement?

Comment: Can you use PySide2?  The original PySide is frozen, no longer maintained.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362751/installing-pyside-for-python-3-6

Comment: No I have to use Pyside

Comment: Then try to follow the above link for info on how to use it with Python 3.6...maybe you can adapt those instructions for 3.8.

Comment: You could download the .tar.gz from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/PySide/#files), extract it and build the library from source. But that's pretty complicated if you are not familiar with such things, and it is most likely not the solution you are looking for. So I guess installing Python 3.4 or using PySide2 is the way to go.